# Python counting all instances of a value which has more than one key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**Jump to the EDIT for a better explanation!**

I have tried to get this problem solved for several hours now and my head is aching (especially because I did already solve it earlier but can't remember how, the script in which I use my solution is stored on a caomputer at school).

Ok so this is my problem. In a given sequence of A's, T's, G's and C's (yup that's DNA) I have to find all the amino acids and count how many there are of them. In layman terms it comes down to this.

I have to search the sequence for certain patterns (also called codons) these are three letter long sequences of A's and/or T's and/or G's and/or C's. Each amino acid has at least one codon associated with it. My job is to count the amount of occurences of each amino acid.

In the second [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table) you'll see the amino acid's to the left and the associated codons to the right.

I have a dictionary set up like so:

```
    aaDic = {'ttt': 'F', 'tct': 'S', 'tat': 'Y', 'tgt': 'C',
    'ttc': 'F', 'tcc': 'S', 'tac': 'Y', 'tgc': 'C',
    'tta': 'L', 'tca': 'S', 'taa': '*', 'tga': '*',
    'ttg': 'L', 'tcg': 'S', 'tag': '*', 'tgg': 'W',
    'ctt': 'L', 'cct': 'P', 'cat': 'H', 'cgt': 'R',
    'ctc': 'L', 'ccc': 'P', 'cac': 'H', 'cgc': 'R',
    'cta': 'L', 'cca': 'P', 'caa': 'Q', 'cga': 'R',
    'ctg': 'L', 'ccg': 'P', 'cag': 'Q', 'cgg': 'R',
    'att': 'I', 'act': 'T', 'aat': 'N', 'agt': 'S',
    'atc': 'I', 'acc': 'T', 'aac': 'N', 'agc': 'S',
    'ata': 'I', 'aca': 'T', 'aaa': 'K', 'aga': 'R',
    'atg': 'M', 'acg': 'T', 'aag': 'K', 'agg': 'R', 
    'gtt': 'V', 'gct': 'A', 'gat': 'D', 'ggt': 'G',
    'gtc': 'V', 'gcc': 'A', 'gac': 'D', 'ggc': 'G',
    'gta': 'V', 'gca': 'A', 'gaa': 'E', 'gga': 'G',
    'gtg': 'V', 'gcg': 'A', 'gag': 'E', 'ggg': 'G'
   }
```

I can of course count the amount of occurences of each codon but since there's more than one codon associated with each Amino Acid I really need the sum of specific codons.

```
    for codons in aaDic:
    s.count(codons)
```

(s is the sequence of a,t,c,g in the code above). For example:

tta,ttg,ctt,ctc,cta,ctg are all associated with the amino acid 'L', so I need to sum of all occurences of tta,ttg,ctt,ctc,cta,ctg to get the total amount of occurences of the amino acid 'L'.

I hope I am clear enough, it's a little hard to explain, especially after trying to do it so long for yourself and failing at it (which usually indicates you have little to no idea of what you are doing, at least that's the case with me :D)

**EDIT:**

Let me try to make myself somewhat more clear:

1. We are given a sequence consisting exlusively of the letters A, T, C and G.
2. We have to parse this sequence three by three.

> suppose the sequence is "TTCTTACTC"
>   we get "TTC", "TTA", "CTC"
>
> We now look up these keys in the dictionary and we find the associated amino acids:
>   TTC is F
>   TTA is L
>   CTC is L
>
> We need to count and store in a list the number of F's, L's and any other value (FLIMVSPTAY*HQNKDECWRSG) in the dictionary.
>
> The desired output would be a dictionary like so:

```
{L:total no. of the amino acid 'L' in the sequence, S:total no. of the amino acid 'S' in the sequence, ...}
```

Comment: Be careful using `.count`, because it doesn't respect the codon boundaries, e.g. `'aacgag'.count('cga') == 1` when you probably want 0.

Comment: The DNA sequence should be parsed three by three?

Comment: Technically, no it isn't homework. I'm in college and we are allowed to use any resource we want. We are just given a task and we have to finish it and present it at the end of the week. The actual assignment is a little more complicated than this but this is the part I need to tackle.

Comment: Yes the DNA should be parsed three by three...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Python 2.7 or above, you can use `collections.Counter` to count the amino acids.  First, split your base sequence into codons, then count the amino acids corresponding to each codon:

```
base_seq = "atcgtgagt"
codons = [base_seq[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(base_seq), 3)]
amino_acid_counts = collections.Counter(aaDict[c] for c in codons)
```

Note that the generator expression `(aaDict[c] for c in codons)` generates a sequence of amino acids, regardless by which codons they were encoded.

If you use an earlier version of Python, you can also use a plain dictionary for counting:

```
amino_acid_counts = dict.fromkeys(aaDict.values(), 0)
for c in codons:
    amino_acid_counts[aaDict[c]] += 1
```

Comment: this results in `codons` being `['atc', 'gtg', 'agt']`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have 2.7+, you can still use a `defaultdict`:

```
counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
for k in aaDic:
    counts[aaDic[k]] += 1
```

Comment: Just tried it but this isn't what I am looking for. What this does is, it counts how often a certain value occurs in the given dictionary. What I need is something else, I'll edit my post and try to explain better.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
y = {}
for x in aaDic.items():
    y[x[1]] = []
for x in aaDic.items():
    y[x[1]].append(x[0])
```

Then you can find all the values with X keys with:

```
xkv = [ k for k in y.keys() if len(y[k]) == X ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using codons split from @sven-marnach:

```
base_seq = "atcgtgagt"

# split sequence, 3 by 3
codons = [base_seq[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(base_seq), 3)]

# for each codon we have, obtain his associated amino_acid from aaDic
amino_acids = map(aaDic.get, base_seq)
# here, amino_acids is ['I', 'V', 'S']

i_count = amino_acids.count('I')
# and so on
```

Then you can assemble your resulting dict with:

```
aa_names = set(aaDic.values())
return dict((aa_name, amino_acids.count(aa_name) for aa_name in aa_names))
```